# Rails Postgres migrations: invalid type name "jsonb USING content::jsonb" or invalid type name "jsonb USING CAST(content AS jsonb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

Ruby 2.7.3
Rails 6.1.3.1
PG 1.2.3
PostgreSQL 12.7

I'm in the process of migrating a Rails  4 app to rails 6. After a large number of gem changes my migrations are now failing on table change which was changing a column to of type JSONB

The original content of the migration which now fails is

```
change_column :pages, :content, 'jsonb USING CAST(content AS jsonb)', null: false, default: '[]'
```

I tried getting rid of the cast like:

```
change_column :pages, :content, 'jsonb', null: false, default: '[]'
```

Which then throws the error

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "content" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING content::jsonb".
```

If I then switch it to this style it blows up in the same manner as the first style

```
    change_column :pages, :content, 'jsonb USING content::jsonb', null: false, default: '[]'
```

Throws the error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 1: SELECT 'jsonb USING CAST(content AS jsonb)'::regtype::oid
               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "jsonb USING CAST(content AS jsonb)"
```

Any thoughts on what the correct syntax is here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `using` with the casting (I know, sounds weird saying using twice!)

```
change_column :pages, :content, :jsonb, using: "content::JSONB", null: false, default: '[]'
```

and see if that works.